# What is Java bytecode injection?

Tags: java, bytecode

What exactly is Java bytecode injection and why would one use it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Java code compiles into bytecode (`Foo.java ->> Foo.class`).  Bytecode injection is modifying `Foo.class`at runtime to inject code into it right before its loaded and run.

Imagine a scenario where I want to find out how many times method

```
public void bar();
```

is invoked in `Foo.class`.  I could write an agent using `java.lang.instrument` that intercepts `Foo.class` during class load, modifies it using [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) so that `bar()` calls `com.amir.agent.incrementCount()` on method entry.

Now I can run my program:

```
$java -javagent:MyAgent Foo  //assuming Foo has a main() defined
```

and at runtime, `Foo.class` will not only do its normal work, it will also do work I defined in `MyAgent` each time `bar()` is invoked.

For a pointer on writing an agent from scratch, start [here](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19309.html).

Answer (score 3):

First Google search gives an interesting read [Java Programming: Bytecode Injection](https://web.archive.org/web/20100716150350/http://www.pabrantes.net/blog/space/start/2008-03-24/1)